# how to get sql minsize property from file header via powershell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am interested in some way to grab the smallest size a sql log file can shrink to.
from reading this blog: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22661.sql-server-misleading-database-initial-size-label.aspx 
I understand I need to grab somehow the minsize (also known as initial size) value out of the file header.
how do I accomplish this?

Comment: So, you need to connect to some instance, get all Databases and their initial size, via PowerShell? You need only LOG info, or ROWS too?

Answer (score 1):

To get all Databases and their initial size, via PowerShell, on some instance you can use this:

```
Import-Module SQLPS -DisableNameChecking 
$instance = 'SERVER\INSTANCE'
$results = @()

try {
    $sqlres = Invoke-SQLcmd -Server $instance -Database master 'SELECT  [name],(size * 8 / 1024) InitialSize FROM sys.master_files WHERE [type] = 1'

    ForEach($st in $sqlres) {
        $dbinfo = @{            
                Name = $st.Name
                InitialSize = $st.InitialSize
        } 
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $dbinfo     
    }
} catch {
    "error when running Invoke-SQLcmd "+$instance
    Write-Host($error)
}

$results | export-csv -Path D:\sql_db_info.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will write databases names and initial size into `D:\sql_db_info.csv` file.

NOTE: in query I use `[type] = 1` to get info on LOG files, if you need ROWS use `[type] = 0`, if you need all - remove WHERE statement.